# .odx Files in BizTalk 2009 (VS2008 IDE) Fail to open. "Unspecified Error"

Tags: visual-studio, biztalk

Okay, I'm not sure if this is an SO question, or a ServerFault question, but I figured I'd post here first.

I have a BizTalk project which works like a champ for its original design.  It's been deployed and it's working fine.  Today, I went in to add some new functionality by modifying one of my orchestrations.  When I attempted to open it, I got a message which simply stated: "The operation could not be completed.  Unspecified error."

I've closed the IDE and re-opened; I've restarted the machine; I've even allowed Microsoft Updates to run and restart the machine.

Everything else opens just fine (.xsd files, .btms, etc.) so it appears only to be the orchestrations which are failing.

Has anyone ever encountered a similar issue and resolved it (short of reinstalling BizTalk/VS, or blowing the orchs away and rebuilding)?

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: biztalk blow up?  never... ;) .  I have seen it too many times something happens and all the sudden biztalk dies.  Did you try deleting your user files?  Did you do any upgrades from 2006 to 2009 ?

Comment: @Nix - I have not deleted any files.  Presuming you're talking about the user profile I can certainly give that a try (it'd be easier than blowing away biztalk and reinstalling).  This is a fresh install of 2K9- no upgrade.

Comment: How did this go for you?  Did deleting the user file work?

Comment: Tried it first thing this morning.  No dice.

Comment: Is this all of your orchestrations?  Or just a few?  If just a few are they very large?

Comment: It's all of them.  Some are big, but others are very basic.  My error has changed: the first time I try to open them (now) I get "Reference Not Set to an Instance of an Object".  Then (if I try again) it changes back to "Unspecified Error."  I thought it might be that the files had become disassocaited with the project, but I copied them to a new directory, deleted the files from the project, and reimported them, and that didn't do any good either...

Answer (score 0):

I haven't specifically seen the error you mention, but there are at least two hotfixes for the dev tools and the orchestration designer that you might want to look into... maybe one of them fixes it for you:

- http://support.microsoft.com/kb/977428/en-us
- http://support.microsoft.com/kb/979153